# Animate custom refresh lightning-button-icon LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, locker-service

I want animate a lightning-button-icon as the standard Salesforce refresh button in 
LWC. I've already seen a related question but the answer was not conclusive, at this point I don't know if it's possible.

```
<lightning-button-icon  icon-name="utility:refresh" alternative-text="Refresh" class="slds-p-around_xx-small" onclick={refreshTable}></lightning-button-icon>
```

I've tried using the icon-class atribute but according to the documentation "Only Lightning Design System utility classes are currently supported with icon-class."

I was able to do it in the dev console by adding a breakpoint in refreshTable and edit a class I've created before,

```
.refreshRotate { animation: rotate .4s linear infinite; }
```

add " svg". This because if I create the class as "refreshRotate svg {" it doesn't affect the svg. I was then able to toggle it with

```
e.target.classList.toggle("refreshRotate");
```

I can't Access the DOM in JS either, other than query selector but since the svg it's not in the same namespace i can't access it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey, were you able to do it in lwc? I am stuck on a similar situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do it using the markup of lightning-button-icon. I guess locker service is preventing me to access the svg inside this component so declare it as this.

LWC Markup

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border" title="Refresh" alternative-text="Refresh" onclick={refreshTimeline}>
    <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
        <use xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg?cache=9.28.0#refresh"></use>
    </svg>
</button>
```

LWC Controller

```
const buttonIcon = evt.target.querySelector('.slds-button__icon');
buttonIcon.classList.add('refreshRotate');
return refreshApex(this.wiredActivities)
    .then(() => {
        buttonIcon.classList.remove('refreshRotate');
    });
```

LWC CSS (rotate is an animation already created for lwc)

```
.refreshRotate {
    animation: rotate .4s;
}
```

Comment: i use above code but icon not animate

Comment: @RijwanMohammed, if you add the class on the developer console and toggle it are you able to animate the icon? if not that may be an issue with the css you're using, if so it must be an issue with getting the element and toggling the class in JS.

Comment: Nice work, its annoying the custom refresh doesn't work the same as their base refresh button.